# Не видна переменная внутри функции

Tags: javascript, переменные, отладка, замыкания, область-видимости

Переменная q внутри функции f - локальная, т.е. доступна внутри тела функции. 
Вопрос: почему она недоступна в функции obj.func?

```
var qwe = 1;
function f() {
    var q = {};
    var qwe = 2;
    debugger;
    var obj = {
        a: q,
        func: function() {
            // тут q не видна, а qwe === 1.
            debugger;
        }
    };
    obj.func();
    debugger;
}

f();
```

Вроде как, при создании obj.func, ее [[Scope]] должен ссылаться на объект переменных функции f (т.к. func создана в контексте функции f), но из кода видно, что ссылается на глобальный объект (Переменная qwe равна 1, а не 2).

Comment: Похожий вопрос уже был на днях

Comment: Почему-то obj.func не считается вложенной по отношению к f.

Comment: Очень похоже на баг отладчика. Хром и ie бажат, причем по-разному. фф - окей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле проверка несколько некорректна.

Отладчик показывает реальное состояние скопов.

Пример в хроме:

[image: в хроме]

Как можно заметить в момент вызова функции доступны два скопа:

1. Локальный скоп функции
2. Глобальный скоп.

Некорректность проверки заключается в том, что функция пуста, нет обращений к переменным из скопа функции `f`, соответственно нет замыканий.

При проверке: поиск осуществляется в доступных **в данный момент** скопах, и там действительно нет переменной `q`, а переменная `qwe` - находится в глобальном скопе и имеет значение 1.

---

Если же изменить код, добавив в него замыкание. Предстанет совсем другая картина:

[image: хром с замыканием]

Как можно отметить, добавился скоп *Closure*, в котором и хранится *используемая* переменная `q` из скопа `f`.

И при проверке - он будет определена и иметь значение - пустой объект.

Также стоит обратить внимание, что раз переменная `qwe` не замкнута, она по прежнему будет отдавать `1` при проверке.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте не будем никому верить на слово, а просто запустим код.

```js
var qwe = 1;
function f() {
    var q = { test: "Test" };
    var qwe = 2;
    var obj = {
        a: q,
        func: function() {
            // тут q не видна, а qwe === 1.
            console.log(q); // видна
            console.log(qwe); // 2
        }
    };
    obj.func();
}

f();
```

Comment: Ненене, запустите код автора и посмотрите в дебаггере. Видимо проблема в том, что дебаггер врет (по крайней мере у меня в хроме - врет o_O)

Comment: Т.е. вопрос по сути не "какого хрена себя js так ведет" а "какого хрена дебаггер себя так ведет"

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка Chrome Version 54.0.2840.99 m - дебаггер показывает правильно, а у Вас?

Comment: 55.0.2883.87 m - хромовский дебагер бажит как у автора

Comment: 11 осел - тоже бажит. А вот в фф - норм.

Comment: Я несколько раз сталкивался в этом году с тем что хром в минорных релизах ту или иную штуку ломал в связи с es6-блок скоупом. Вполне вероятно что это из той же оперы, для полной уверенности осталось лишь тикет найти пожалуй.

Answer (score 0):

Переменные были удалены сборщиком мусора ([Оптимизация в V8 и её последствия](https://learn.javascript.ru/memory-management#%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-v8-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%91-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Comment: они не были удалены. Так как они доступны и после вызова функции.

Comment: по ссылке объяснение не очень

Comment: @Grundy в firefox 72 они отображаются, если использются, и undefined, если не используются

Answer (score 0):

если хочешь переменные за пределы функции видеть просто не обЪявляй что это переменная. пример
(не var i = 10; а просто i = 10; без var ) я сам так делаю