# можно ли обратится к лексическому окружению функции напрямую

Tags: javascript

мне просто интересно можно так или нет, ведь пока есть `x`, то `d` тоже есть в окружении, или из `х` обязательно надо ссылаться на `d`, чтобы оно жило?

то есть не вот так

```
let a = () => {
  let d = 5
  return () => d
}
let x = a()
console.log(x())
```

а как то так

```
let a = () => {
  let d = 5
  return () => {}
}
let x = a()
console.log(x().`any Obj.d` или x.`anyObj.d`);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### К лексическому окружению напрямую обратиться нельзя.

---

Однако, можно воспользоваться тем, что *прямой вызов `eval`* выполняется в локальной области видимости.

```js
let a = () => {
  let d = 5;
  let d2 = 11;
  return (prop) => {
    return eval(prop);
  }
}
let x = a();
console.log(x('d'), x('d2'));
```

Comment: прикольный хак)

Comment: @Armen, но лучше не используйте его.

Comment: Интересно, а сборщик мусора никогда не чистит такие переменные? Или это наличие eval предотвращает очистку замыкания?

Comment: @МаксимВишневский да не написал же ради интереса такие штуки манят

Comment: @vp_arth пока есть x думаю некогда

Comment: Да вроде [не течёт](https://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/ay6njq3v/) :) Странно)

Comment: @vp_arth, а почему должно течь? У тебя одна переменная с массивом и ты только ее одну и используешь.

Comment: Я же функцию заново вызываю, не? О, наверное, нужно корень сохранить)

Comment: @vp_arth, ты какую функцию-то вызываешь? :-)

Comment: Одну маленькую функцию, в которой замкнут один массив)

Comment: @vp_arth, да, это наличие `eval` ломает оптимизацию: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/604390/186999 - так как движок не может угадать какие могут использоваться, а какие нет, поэтому оставляет все. При этом учитывается только _прямой_ вызов. В случае не прямого, так как он обращается только к глобальному скопу, локальные переменные не замыкаются

Comment: @vp_arth _Одну маленькую функцию, в которой замкнут один массив)_ - по идее после того как ты `p` переписал - старый массив вместе с функцией уже не нужен и может быть удален :)

Comment: Да, я уже понял, спасибо)